# Unable to install erlang

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies, erlang

I am trying to install `Erlang` for `RabbitMQ` on `CentOS release 6.4 (Final)`

> yum install -y erlang

It gives me the following error :

```
Error: Package: erlang-R12B-5.12.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Requires: libodbc.so.1()(64bit)
```

I can't find solution for `libodbc.so.1` 
I also installed `unixODBC` and `unixODBC-devel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R12B release is from 2008. There was an update in how it handles ODBC libs in R13A, according to the readme file from that release:

```
          The configure script of the odbc application now also looks
          for odbc libraries in lib64 and lib/64 directories when
          building on a 64-bit system.
```

This may explain why an older release is having trouble with locating the right ODBC library.

If you don't have any need for that specific version (and I sincerely hope you don't!), you should instead add the Erlang repository to get the current release:

```
 wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
 rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

If you don't want do that, you could use the version in the  `epel` repository is R14B, which is at least from this decade (2010 to be precise). To start using that repository, run

```
 su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm'
```

and then try installing erlang again.

Answer (score 2):

You can install erlang using [erlang-solution](https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/) repo

- Install repo

  `wget http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm`

  `rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm`
- Install erlang

  `sudo yum install erlang`